# How do i create a special Access query

Tags: database

would like to query a field in a query - arrival date -

the query should be dynamic and only the following Saturday should be filtered

For example, this Saturday is July 22nd, 2023 if I run the query from Sunday 07/16/2023 to Saturday 07/22 execute, only the 22.07.2023 should be filtered for the day of arrival